# Google app script Trigger timings not comings right

Tags: google-apps-script

I am running a google app script which creates a trigger at 5 specified times. When i run the script, the trigger is created but the timings are the time i created the trigger and not the timings specified in the code. when i logged the times created in the script , all comes out correctly . Also the time Zone for the bound spreadsheet and the script both are the same too.

```
function copyResponses() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssName = ss.getName()
 
  var re=/(q)(\D*)(\d+)/i;    // to get the number after q
  var quizNumber=ssName.match(re)[3]
 
  ssSheet = ss.getSheetByName(quizNumber + 'QSummary')
  var dateOfQuiz = ssSheet.getRange('G1').getValue()
//  Logger.log(dateOfQuiz)
  var dateOfQuizinMS = dateOfQuiz.getTime()
  // console.log(dateOfQuiz,dateOfQuizinMS)
  var firstReportTime = new Date(dateOfQuizinMS + ((21 * 60 + 45) * 60 * 1000));
  // Logger.log(firstReportTime)
 
  var secondReportTime = new Date(dateOfQuizinMS + ((22 * 60) * 60 * 1000));
  // Logger.log(secondReportTime)
 
  var thirdReportTime = new Date(dateOfQuizinMS + ((22 * 60 + 30) * 60 * 1000));
  // Logger.log(thirdReportTime)
 
  var fourthReportTime = new Date(dateOfQuizinMS + (((24 + 9) * 60+30) * 60 * 1000));
  // Logger.log(fourthReportTime)
 
  var fifthReportTime = new Date(dateOfQuizinMS + (((24 + 21) * 60 + 30) * 60 * 1000));
  // Logger.log(fifthReportTime)
 
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('getResponses')
    .timeBased()
    .at(new Date(firstReportTime))
    .create();
    Logger.log(new Date(firstReportTime))
 
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('getResponses')
    .timeBased()
    .at(new Date(secondReportTime))
    .create();
  Logger.log(new Date(secondReportTime))

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('getResponses')
    .timeBased()
    .at(new Date(thirdReportTime))
    .create();
    Logger.log(new Date(thirdReportTime))
 
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('getResponses')
    .timeBased()
    .at(new Date(fourthReportTime))
    .create();
 
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('getResponses')
    .timeBased()
    .at(new Date(fifthReportTime))
    .create();
}
```

when I log the timings and the time zone are all correct but the triggers that are created show the time the script was run and the triggers ran too . But the problem was the timing was different.

this is the log of the different times

```
7:24:06 PM  Info    Fri Feb 17 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2023
7:24:06 PM  Info    Fri Feb 17 21:45:00 GMT+05:30 2023
7:24:06 PM  Info    Fri Feb 17 22:00:00 GMT+05:30 2023
7:24:06 PM  Info    Fri Feb 17 22:30:00 GMT+05:30 2023
7:24:06 PM  Info    Sat Feb 18 09:30:00 GMT+05:30 2023
7:24:06 PM  Info    Sat Feb 18 21:30:00 GMT+05:30 2023
```

Comment: What is the content of your `appsscripts.json` file?

Comment: {
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "sheets": {
    "macros": [{
      "menuName": "Untitled macro",
      "functionName": "Untitledmacro"
    }, {
      "menuName": "Untitled macro 1",
      "functionName": "Untitledmacro1"
    }]
    }
  }

Comment: I think i got it. Seems the trigger dates were before the present date. that is why it happened. Thanks a lot and sorry for the trouble

Comment: no problem, I'm glad you found the solution. Can you post the answer bellow, please? Thanks.

Comment: Only change was in the spreadsheet from where the date is taken. I put a date in the future and it worked fine